# is_archive() content being shown instead of is_category()

Tags: categories, theme-development, templates, template-hierarchy

### My Issue:

If I browse to `http://mysite/category/mycategory`, the `if (is_category())` content isn't displayed, **the `if(is_archive())` is shown instead.**

### My code:

`archive.php`:

```
<?php include('includes/resultlist.php')?>
```

`search.php`:

```
<?php include('includes/resultlist.php')?>
```

`includes/resultlist.php`:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

            <div class="main">

<?php if (is_archive()) { ?>

            <h1>Artigos publicados em <?php single_month_title(' '); ?></h1>

<?php } else if (is_search()) { ?>

            <h1>Resultados para "<?php the_search_query(); ?>"</h1>

<?php } else if (is_category()) { ?>

            <h1>Resultados para categoria "<?php the_category(); ?>"</h1>

<?php }

if ( have_posts() ) while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>

                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                por <span class="date"><?php the_author(); ?></span> em 
                <span class="date"><?php the_date(); ?></span>

                <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Leia mais</a></p>

             <?php } 

else {?> 

            <h2>Nada encontrado</h2>
            <p>Desculpe, não encontramos o que você procurava!</p>

<?php }

include('pagination.php');

?>

            </div><!-- /main -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

### What I tried:

Created a `category.php` file with the contents: `<?php include('includes/resultlist.php')?>` but the issue persits. I included some garbage text on the end of category.php and it shows on the end of the rendered page, so the file is being called, I suppose.

### My environment:

LAMP Ubuntu 64 bit with apache, mysql and php installed with default options via apt-get.

Comment: What information is it showing instead? `if(is_archive())` information?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Yes. I will update the question, thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A category page is an archive page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_archive). So `is_archive()` will `return true` on a category page. Try to push down `is_category()` further, or use `is_category()` before `is_archive()`.

**Like This**

```
if ( is_search() )
{
    // Search Result content
}
elseif( is_category() )
{
    // Category archive content
}
// check for tag, taxonomy, date before 
elseif ( is_archive() )
{
    // Default archive content for *every* type of archive
}
else
{
    // Default content for non-archives
}
```